# Trying to solve error 'only integer scalar arrays can be converted to a scalar index'

Tags: python, numpy, neural-network

Code:

```
X_train = X_train.reshape(X_train.shape[0], X_train[1], X_train[2], 1)
X_validation = X_validation.reshape(X_validation.shape[0], X_validation[1], 
X_validation[2], 1)
X_test = X_train.reshape(X_test[0], X_test.shape[1], X_test[2], 1)
```

Im trying to solve the error while running the code up here.

```
only integer scalar arrays can be converted to a scalar index
```

The error occuring in this line:

```
X_train = X_train.reshape(X_train.shape[0], X_train[1], X_train[2], 1)
```

but I dont know why there is this error.
I tried to put the line in a seperate tuple. This isn't working.
Could anyone help me?

Comment: did you look at `X_train.shape[0], X_train[1], X_train[2], 1`?  It should be a tuple of 4 numbers.

Comment: What do you mean it should be a tuple of 4 numbers? Could you explain it more? Thank you

Comment: Did you look at it?  The problem should be obvious when you do.  If not reread the `reshape` docs.